# Passing a parameter from a column in a SSRS chart

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS, I have a chart that displays data in columns by month.  I want to be able to click a column in the chart and go to another report with that month as the parameter for the new report.  Is that possible?  If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. This is called "drill-through". You just have to right-click on the column, open "properties", go to the "action" section and check "Go to report". Chose your report and add the field as parameter to this new report.

Forgive me if the labels are wrong, my client uses a foreign version of SSRS and I can't remember all labels by heart.

Hope this helped!

Comment: That works!  I had tried that, but I didn't have all the parameters set up properly.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please mark as answer when you get a chance. Have fun with SSRS ;-)